# Add AdSense Code After The 1st Paragraph Pure PHP

Tags: php

There are a lot of code samples that explain how to add the AdSense code after the “n”th paragraph in WordPress. However, I wasn't able to find the implementation for a project made with pure `PHP`.

The task looks primitive while using `jQuery`. But I’m trying to avoid such a method because of the possible sanctions from Google.

Can anyone provide me a piece of code how to cope with such a task without any framework? I suspect that the hint is to use the `DOMDocument()` method. But I’m not so experienced in PHP to achieve my goal.

For instance, I can’t even realize what should be `$html` in the string below:

```
$dom->loadHTML($html)
```

What exactly and how I need to parse?

Let’s imagine I have some function which “echoes” my description:

```
function desc()
{
    global $data;

    foreach ($data as $value)
    {
       $desc = $value['descr'];
       echo $desc;
    }
}
```

I need to find the 1st (2nd, 3rd ...) "p" tag in my description and add my AdSense code after it.

Can anyone assist me with such a task?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply you can just use explode and for loop for this case .

```
$html  = '<p>This is a first paragraph</p>
<p>This is second paragraph</p>
<p>This is third paragraph</p>
<p>This is fourth paragraph</p>';

$content = $html ; //your content or function goes here;
$content = explode("</p>", $content);

$first  = 1;
for ($i = 0; $i<count($content); $i++) {
if ($i == $first) {
 // put your ads code here
    echo $adscode;
}
echo $content[$i];
}
```

To find 2nd, or 3rd paragraph you can use $i array index

Comment: Wow! Thanks, Ryan AW! It's really easy! Your explanation is excellent!